# Limit involving average of exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^\frac{1}{n}  + e^\frac{2}{n} +....+e^\frac{n}{n}}{n}.$$
My attempt is as folllows.
By the geometric series formula,
$$\frac {e^\frac{1}{n}  + e^\frac{2}{n} +....+e^\frac{n}{n}}{n}=\frac{(e-1) e^{1/n}}{n(e^{1/n}-1)}.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^\frac{1}{n}  + e^\frac{2}{n} +....+e^\frac{n}{n}}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(e-1) e^{1/n}}{n(e^{1/n}-1)} = \infty.$$
Is this correct?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(e-1) e^{1/n}}{n(e^{1/n}-1)}\ne \infty$  If you show your computation, we will spot your mistake.

Comment: @Stupid: I edited your post to read a bit better. I think you received the downvotes because of the formatting. The amount of help you get is proportional to your upvotes, so it's worth putting in the time to make your question readable (for future reference).

Comment: thanks   a lots @ parsiad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is to set $1/n = \Delta x$  Then$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^\frac{1}{n}  + e^\frac{2}{n} +....+e^\frac{n}{n}}{n}= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0+ }\sum_{k=1}^n{\Delta x e^{k\Delta x}}=\int_0^1{e^x dx} = e-1
$$

Comment: briallant solution @ saulspatz,,

Comment: Thank you, but it's not really brilliant.  The expression is an average of function values, and that's a very common way to think of an integral.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is equivalent to Siong Thye Goh's answer

Answer (score 2):

You are right to claim that by the geometric series formula,
$$
\frac{e^{1/n}+\cdots+e^{n/n}}{n}=\frac{\left(e-1\right)e^{1/n}}{n\left(e^{1/n}-1\right)}.
$$
However, your next steps are incorrect. We have to proceed carefully since $e^{1/n}-1$ approaches zero as $n$ gets large.
Using a Taylor series,
$$
n\left(e^{1/n}-1\right)=n\left(\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right)=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(e^{1/n}-1\right)=1.
$$
Putting this all together,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{1/n}+\cdots+e^{n/n}}{n}=e-1.
$$

Comment: thanks.. parsiad

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp(i/n)}{n} \le \frac{ne}{n}=e$$

Hence your solution is wrong.

Hint to solve the problem:

> Riemann sum.

Comment: thanks  sion thye Goh

Answer (score 1):

*Just added for your curiosity since you already received good answers to the question.*

Continuing the Taylor series expansion as in parsiad's answer, we can have very good approximations of the partial sums even for very small values of $n$
$$S_n=\frac{e^{1/n}+\cdots+e^{n/n}}{n}=\frac{\left(e-1\right)e^{1/n}}{n\left(e^{1/n}-1\right)}$$ $$S_n=(e-1)\left(1+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{12 n^2}-\frac{1}{720 n^4}+\frac{1}{30240
   n^6}-\frac{1}{1209600 n^8} \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 2.7182818284590452354 & \color{red}{2.718281}7934724389398 \\
 2 & 2.1835015495795866911 & \color{red}{2.1835015495}447755709 \\
 3 & 2.0205427648666035402 & \color{red}{2.02054276486}59977459 \\
 4 & 1.9420071331148973837 & \color{red}{1.9420071331148}632274 \\
 5 & 1.8958338026286923933 & \color{red}{1.8958338026286}887237 \\
 6 & 1.8654476448430682793 & \color{red}{1.86544764484306}76864 \\
 7 & 1.8439374993059529344 & \color{red}{1.843937499305952}8075 \\
 8 & 1.8279112064429921886 & \color{red}{1.8279112064429921}552 \\
 9 & 1.8155093460652278961 & \color{red}{1.8155093460652278}858 \\
 10 & 1.8056275828122667028 & \color{red}{1.805627582812266}6992
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thanks  a  @claude leibvici

Comment: @Stupid. You are welcome ! Moreover, the coefficients are pretty well known. Have a look at sequence A060055 in OEIS.